# how to overide childnode value with dynamic content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My requirement is to update the dynamic content to the child element. I tried to iterate the parent elements one by one and trying to update the child elements  but I am unable can anyone guide me please?Thanks

```
<section id="parent_sec">
  <div id="parent1">
    <div id="childdiv">default1</div>
  </div>
```

I tried like belo

```
  function getTragetElement(elem, tem){
      var tem1 = 'childiv';
      for (i = 0; i <= elem.length - 1; i++) {
                if(elem[i].childdiv!= undefined && elem[i].childdiv!= null){
                    elem[i].childdiv.innerHTML  = "12345";
                    break;
                }else{
                    getTragetElement(elem[i], tem1);
                }

            }
  }
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent_sec");
var childElements  = parentDiv.children;
getTragetElement(childElements[0], 'childdiv')
```

Answer (score 0):

first when you pass in the array as a parameter don't declare an index value just pass in the array and let only the function declare the value (as your function is already doing).

And also take out the .childdiv when changing the content of the child div, because this doesn't work and there is no need for calling the child div, because the array with the index declaration, in your case - elem[i] - already contains the child div itself.

so here is a edited example:

```
 function getTragetElement(elem, tem){

      var tem1 = 'childiv';

        for (i = 0; i <= elem.length ; i++) {
              if(elem[i]!= undefined && elem[i] != null){
                     elem[i].innerHTML  = "12345";
              }else{
                  getTragetElement(elem[i], tem1);
              }
         }    
 }

    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent1");
    var childElements  = parentDiv.children;
    //passing in the array childElenents without an index value 
    getTragetElement(childElements, 'childdiv')
```